# Checked Box is not getting VISIBLE

Tags: android

I am new to Android Application in which i need a help my checkbox which is been placed in gridview is not getting visible when i click the icon which is been placed in Toolbar

Code:-

```
public class MyActivity extends Fragment {
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_room_summary,null);
     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     initializeValue();
     return myView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_dash){
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Not working
        return true;
    }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void initializeValue(){
  adapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, R.layout.activity_list, listMy);
}


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<My> {
  @Override
  public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work like that, because the `CheckBox` is in `GridView` so you need to notify the adapter.

Try this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Fragment {

   boolean mIsCheckBoxVisible;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_room_summary,null);
     setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     initializeValue();
     return myView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_dash){
        mIsCheckBoxVisible = true;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void initializeValue(){
  adapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, R.layout.activity_list, listMy);
}


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<My> {
  @Override
  public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

     if(mIsCheckBoxVisible){
       checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
       checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: just want to ask how i can know which checkbox is been checked and what is the textview value of that checked one

Comment: i tried that example i didnt get the answer plz help me out if possible using above example

Comment: This should work, did you call notifyDataSetChanged(); after updating the boolean? otherwise i need to see your code, to know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you also need to refresh your adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```